# React image can't be loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I'm trying to to currently add an svg to my React-App.
I've got a nginX running that currently only servs one picture (localhost:80/ban.svg is reachable by browser and returns the correct icon).

```
import React from "react";

export class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <img src={"localhost:80/ban.svg"}/>
    }
}
```

Above Code doesn't work tho. It just says "Could not load the image" and displays the default browser error picture.

I'm fairly new to React, so sorry if this is something really obvious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try adding ```http://``` before ```localhost```, also you can remove the port, 80 is default.

Comment: Thanks @CevaComic! the 'http://' fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react":
export class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return <img src={"http://localhost:80/ban.svg"}/>
}
}
```

Try this